# Retrieving two-dimensional array from QR code image

Tags: c#, qr-code

I need to retrieve a two-dimensional array from the image of QR code. Result must be like this:

```
{
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
    {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
    {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1},
    {0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
    {1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1},
    {0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1},
    {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1},
    {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1},
    {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0}
}
```

C# program should take .bmp image, get qr code on it and return this qr code as two-dimensional array of "1" for black pixels and "0" for white pixels

Here is my code that takes bmp and returns text on it using MultiFormatReader from zxing lib

```
Bitmap originalBitmap = new Bitmap(pathOfBmp);

LuminanceSource source;
source = new BitmapLuminanceSource(originalBitmap);
BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
Result result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap);


Console.WriteLine(result.Text);
```

But its not an array, just decoded text

Comment: What library is this? If it's ZXing.Net, have you tried the `RawBytes` property instead?

Comment: Also, without a sample QR code or details of how the data is encoded, it's going to be hard to advise you on how to get the right result.

Comment: Is this some educational assignment and you are actually supposed to do all the grunt work by hand?

Comment: ProgrammingLlama, yes, I tried ZXing.Net.
I don't quite understand which bytes RawBytes returns and how to represent them as a two-dimensional array. 
It could be any qr code image

Comment: Fildor, no, its my own project

Comment: No need to decode the data, just get an array from the image

Comment: The structure of the bmp is shown at Wiki. You need to extract the pixels : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: jdweng, sure, but image may consist not only the qr code, but also other information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 1 byte per pixel format with BMP file the code will look like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ConsoleApplication52
{
    class Program
    {
        const string BMP_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.bmp";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(BMP_FILENAME);

            int rows = bitmap.Height;
            int columns = bitmap.Width;

            List<List<byte>> array = new List<List<byte>>();

            for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
            {
                List<byte> rowArray = new List<byte>();
                array.Add(rowArray);
                for(int col = 0; col < columns; col++)
                {
                    Color color = bitmap.GetPixel(col,row);
                    uint bits = (uint)color.ToArgb();
                    for (int bit = 31; bit >= 0; bit--)
                    {
                        uint mask = (uint)(1 << bit);
                        rowArray.Add((byte)((bits & mask) > 0 ? 1 : 0));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If it is only one bit per pixel the code would look like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ConsoleApplication52
{
    class Program
    {
        const string BMP_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.bmp";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(BMP_FILENAME);

            int rows = bitmap.Height;
            int columns = bitmap.Width;

            List<List<byte>> array = new List<List<byte>>();
            uint mask = 0x80; // or 0x8000 for 32 bits
            for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
            {
                List<byte> rowArray = new List<byte>();
                array.Add(rowArray);
                for(int col = 0; col < columns; col++)
                {
                    Color color = bitmap.GetPixel(col,row);
                    uint bits = (uint)color.ToArgb();
                    rowArray.Add((byte)((bits & mask) > 0 ? 1 : 0));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code, but i tried it on my 41*41 bmp file with qr code and got an array 41*1312. Like every pixel have been representet as 32 bits

Comment: That is what I would expect I using the Wiki page as a reference.   Wiki said bmp was 32 bit format which may be wrong.  Modify code if necessary.  41 * 41 is number of pixels and each pixel contains multiple bits (not sure if it should be 8 or 32).

Comment: Of course. I was wrong. Thank you for your help)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small snippet which uses the classes from ZXing.Net and should deal with different color formats:

```
    const string BMP_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.bmp";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(BMP_FILENAME);
        var source = new BitmapLuminanceSource(bitmap);
        var binary = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
        // perhaps binary.BlackMatrix is already what you want ...
        var blackMatrix = binary.BlackMatrix;
        // ... and there is no need to convert it to another array
        var array = new byte[blackMatrix.Height][];
        for (var row = 0; row < blackMatrix.Height; row++)
        {
            array[row] = new byte[blackMatrix.Width];
            for (var col = 0; col < blackMatrix.Width; col++)
            {
                array[row][col] = blackMatrix[col, row] ? (byte)1 : (byte)0;
            }
        }
    }
```

But perhaps you can also use binary.BlackMatrix directly in your further code.